# Property value is not valid typed data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I am using typed data set in my application and I have a data table with two columns which are of `System.Int32.AllowDBNULL = true` and NULLVALUE = throw exception and default value = 1. I am using this property of datatable in my code like this:

```
 if (rr.ForenameStatus != -1 && rr.ForenameStatus == 0)
{

}
```

but I am getting this error:

> The value for column 'ForenameStatus' in table 'Registrant' is DBNull.

I tried to change `NULLVALUE` of column to `NULL` or empty in dataset properties but I get error:

> property value is not valid

I tried using this:

```
 if (rr.ForenameStatus != System.DBNull.Value && rr.ForenameStatus == 0)
                        {

                        }
```

but It says Operator != can not be applied to operands of int and dbnull

Please suggest me solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Set AllowDBNULL = true and call IsForenameStatusNull method to check on NULL value.

Comment: I see that AllowDBNULL is already set to true and checking if (rr.ForenameStatus != null && rr.ForenameStatus == 0) gives error.

Comment: it's incorrect checking. Try this:
if (IsForenameStatusNull())

Comment: what is IsForenameStatusNull ? I dont have this in my datatable and code gives error on it

Comment: It's auto-generated method of the typed 
DataRow if property option AllowDBNull set to True. Similar methods (Is__propname_Null) are generated for each property if AllowDBNull = True.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (rr.ForenameStatus.ToString()!="" && rr.ForenameStatus == 0)
{

}
```

This is as an alternative. You may try converting the int value to string and compare against empty string to identify the nulls.